# Удаление класса по клику вне блока или на клик по такому же блоку

Tags: jquery

Товарищи, помогите, пожалуйста, советом.

Есть вот такой код, добавляет класс по клику на объект, удаляет тоже только по клику на него же. Хочется, чтобы удалялся и по клику на любую область экрана или по клику на такой же объект. Там 4-5 блоков с одинаковыми классами

```
$(document).on('click', '.ivpa_selectbox .ivpa_title', function(event) {
    var el = $(this).closest('.ivpa_select_wrapper_inner');
    if ( el.hasClass('ivpa_selectbox_opened') ) {
        el.removeClass('ivpa_selectbox_opened');
    }
    else {
        el.addClass('ivpa_selectbox_opened').queue(function(next){
        });
    }
});
```

Добавление такого кода решила проблему удаления по клику на любую область экрана

```
   $(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var div = $(this).find('.ivpa_select_wrapper_inner'); 
    if (!div.is(e.target) 
        && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        div.removeClass('ivpa_selectbox_opened');
    }
});
```

Но вот если нажать на другой блок, предыдущий не скрывается. Подскажите, как решить вопрос. Спасибо!

Посмотреть, как сейчас работает, можно тут - https://pobeda-print.com/product/vizitki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед тем как открыть `select` закройте все открытые.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ivpa_selectbox .ivpa_title', function(event) {
    $('#ivpa-content').find('.ivpa_selectbox_opened').removeClass('ivpa_selectbox_opened')
    ...
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает.

Comment: @ИгорьСкриплюк рад помочь! Если не трудно можете пометить ответ как верный. Спасибо